# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null while changing SRC of img

Tags: javascript, html

I want to when I click on IMG change his src.
This is my div:

```
<div class="character">
<input id="1200" name="vocation_select" type="radio" value="1200" style="display: none" ></input>
<label id="label_profesji" for="1200">
    <img id="1200voc" onclick="onChange(this.id)" src="engine/images/proffesion/1200voc.png" width="34px" height="34px" style="cursor: pointer" title="Bardock"> 
</label>
```

And javascript:

```
<script>
    function onChange(id){
        var names = ("1200voc");
        for (x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
            var prof = document.getElementById(names[x]);
            prof.src = 'engine/images/proffesion/' + names[x] + '.png';  
        }

        var prof = document.getElementById(id);
        prof.src = 'engine/images/proffesion/' + prof.id + '_s.png';     
    }; 
</script>
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null while changing SRC of img

Why this not working?

Comment: how is this a php related question?

Comment: You are calling `onclick="onChangeProfession(this.id)"` but your function is `onChange`

Comment: smells like a typo question to  me, as per the above.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change, but with onclick="onChange(this.id)" still not working.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner there's also a problem with the variable `names`, which has nothing to do with the name of the function.

Comment: you are iterating on all the chars in the string `names`, which is not an array, your HTML elements are not found by `getElementById` then

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well, I'm not so hot with JS, but the OP tagged as php so that's why I ended up in the question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I was referring to "smells like a typo question"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca partly; being the wrong method name call, as per what Eddie found.

Comment: `onclick="onChange(this)"` and `function onChange(ìmg){ img.src='engine/images/proffesion/'+this.id+ '_s.png';  }` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code you do:

```
var names = ("1200voc")
```

then try to access `names` as an array.

So this:

```
for (x = 0; x < names.length; x++) {
    var prof = document.getElementById(names[x]);
    prof.src = 'engine/images/proffesion/' + names[x] + '.png';  
}
```

Means that `names[0]` will return `1`, `names[1]` will return `2`, `names[2]` will return `0` and so on...

Now there's is no element with id of `1` or `2`... so when you do:

```
var prof = document.getElementById(names[x]);
```

you get your error.

What you want is an array of names, so what you should do is:

```
var names = ["1200voc"]
```

This way you can properly loop through `names` as an array in the format you want.

Answer (score -1):

Names isn't an array, it's a string.

Change your line to `var names = ["1200voc"];`

Comment: They also need to change the `id` of the `img` in the html (it's `1200`, not `1200voc`)